# Trying to post data to MongoDB, get status code 200 but fail to post data

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am a newbie to programming.

Now, I am working on a MERN stack project, trying to post data to my mongoDB database, but failed after many attempts.

Database:

There are 2 collections, 'items' and 'users' in the same database. The schemas are as follows:

Item Schema:

```
const mongoose  = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Create Schema
const ItemSchema = new Schema(
  {
  entryDate: {
    type: Date,
    required: true
  },
  leaveDate: {
    type: Date,
    required: true
  }
  },
  {
    collection: 'items'
  }
);

module.exports = Item = mongoose.model('Item', ItemSchema);
```

User Schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Create Schema
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  userName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  Password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});

module.exports = User = mongoose.model('users', UserSchema);
```

Front-end:

```
handleClick = (e) => {
    const API_URL = 'http://localhost:5000/api/users/';

    this.setState({
      startDate: this.handleStartDate(e.target.value),
      endDate: this.handleEndDate(e.target.value)
    });

    const newDate = {
      startDate: this.state.startDate,
      endDate: this.state.endDate
    }

    const data = JSON.stringify(newDate);

    axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: API_URL + 'addnew',
      data: data,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        "Accept": "application/json"
      }
    })
      .then(response => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
          console.log('The status code is : ' + response.status);
        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('-------Failed to add new data. Error occurred.-------');
      });
  };
```

Backend:

```
// @route  POST api/items
// @desc   Create An Item
// @access Public 
router.post('/addnew', function(req, res) {
  const newItem = new Item({
    entryDate: req.body.entryDate,
    leaveDate: req.body.leaveDate
  });

  console.log(newItem);
  // save model to database
  newItem.save(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      res.json({
        success: false,
        message: 'failed to post data'
      })
    } else {
      res.json({
        success: true,
        message: 'success to post data'
      })
    }
  })
});
```

I have tested the backend API with Postman, the status code is 200, but returns the error message, shown below as in the screenshot:

[Screenshot of Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uCRc.png)

I am not sure where I went wrong, my guess is that data of the schema 'Item' could not be saved into the collection 'items', but I have no clue what I should do.

I will be really appreciated for every little help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try to change like this

```
const Item = require('path/to/ItemSchemas');

// @route  POST api/items
// @desc   Create An Item
// @access Public 
router.post('/addnew', function(req, res) {
  const newItem = new Item({
    entryDate: req.body.entryDate,
    leaveDate: req.body.leaveDate
  });

  console.log(newItem);
  // save model to database. Since newItem hasn't been added to the db, we used Item.save instead
  Item.save(newItem, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      // save to db failed!
      res.status(500).json({
        success: false,
        message: err
      })
    } else {
      res.json({
        success: true,
        message: 'success to post data'
      })
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I tried this code, but I got '500 - Internal Server Error' when testing with Postman. Since I created two collections 'items' and 'users' for the 2 schemas respectively, will this automatically save the data to collection 'items' or I need to specify in the code?

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that, sorry I read throught your post to fast. Since you instanciate your instance with the item constructir `const newItem = new Item....` You should not use `User.save`but `Item.save`. Also, you should add some log on your connection to make sure you connect to your mongo instance without any error